# Anyone success which In App Purchase ANE for Adobe air?

Tags: ios, air, adobe, in-app-purchase

I have tried two versions of In [Freshplanet](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-In-App-Purchase)
and [StickSports](https://github.com/StickSports/ANE-In-App-Purchase)
but both of them failed. When I try to get product info, no error throws out, just empty array returned in success handler. Is there anyone success with In App Purchase in Flash? Following are my info:

- Bundle ID matchs App ID. YES.
- One binary version was uploaded to Appstore and rejected later. YES.
- in app purchase Product status: Ready to submit and Waiting for review(two products).
- Correct product ID: I tried both full and short one: "testproduct" and "APP_BUNDDLE_ID.testproduct" but both fail.

Comment: You might find more in app purchase ANEs here: http://www.as3gamegears.com/category/air-native-extension/

Answer (score 2):

http://distriqt.com

Very easy to set up with clear instructions. Also supports Google Play Store.

App currently in the Apple App Store using the ANE.

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/prime-mover/id595928344?mt=8